# How do I get attributes from a pyqtgraph TextItem?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm using `pyqtgraph` and trying to recover the properties for my `TextItem` class objects added to a given graph.

Although it looks like it's a simple task, I can't figure out how to extract this and the [documentation](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/textitem.html) didn't help much.

Here's a snippet:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

def refreshScreen(AnnotationsList):
        for i in range(len(AnnotationsList)):
              c = AnnotationsList[i]

              # Now I need to extract information from the annotations:
              x = c.x()
              print(x)

              y = c.y()
              print(y)

              text = c.text()
              print(text)

              OtherProperties = c.getProperty()
              print(OtherProperties)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    AnnotationsList = []
    c = pg.TextItem(anchor=(0,0), border=pg.mkPen(200, 200, 200))
    c.setText(text='my_annotation', color=(0,0,0))
    # coordinates for annotation
    x = 5
    y = 10
    c.setPos(x,y)
    AnnotationsList = np.append(AnnotationsList, c)

    refreshScreen(AnnotationsList)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I guessed the .x() and .y() and got them right, but knowing how to extract other features would also be important! In the current form, it raises:

```py
AttributeError: 'TextItem' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Of course, @eyllanesc , hope it's better now. The main difficulty is to find how to extract back the properties of those objects, maybe I'm lacking some basic intuition on how to look for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [source code](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/TextItem.html) you see that TextItem has a QGraphicsTextItem that stores the information, so if you want to get the text information you should use that object:

```py
text = c.textItem.toPlainText()
print(text)
```

Comment: That works, thanks! The [QGraphicsTextItem documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qgraphicstextitem.html) also shows how one can extract other attributes as well.